# tailwind CSS applied on react component moves the navigation bar along in remix

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, remix.run, tailwind-elements

I created a React component called `MainNavigation` and using it under my `root.tsx` as my main navigation for my remix project.

[image]

when I apply my CSS to another react component which isnt even a part of main navigation, somehow my main navigation bar moves along with it. Also the components are overlapping with the navigation instead of respecting each others boundaries.

MainNavigation ul class,

```
<ul className="border border-blue-400 flex fixed w-screen mx-auto my-auto py-3">
```

should be respected by the other components such as,

X component,

```
<section className="container mx-auto">
```

As soon as I add m-2 on X component, i.e.,

```
<section className="container mx-auto m-2">
```

the navigation bar moves below,

[image]

instead of staying on top. How can I fix this? thanks

Comment: Use `sticky` instead of `fixed` on the MainNavigation? Otherwise give us more code to work with so we can reproduce what you have. https://play.tailwindcss.com/vANuv9Ngss